# how to migrate a wss 3.0 to another server?

Tags: wss

My site is WSS 3.0 built in 2009. Now I got a high performance server and I want to move my site to that server.

I have installed several dlls into the windows /assembly folder in my old box and have used SharePoint desinger to edit my homepage in my old box.

1. I used `stsadm -backup` to back up my site.
2. I installed WSS 3.0 on the new server and it did run.
3. I used `stsadm -restore` to restore my site but it failed many times .
4. Becasue I can't obtain `gacutil.exe`, I didn't import my dlls into the new server.

Can you help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to help out with as you have pretty much described the whole problem and pointed to the solution.  You should be able to either copy the GACUTIL from the old server or install the Windows SDK on the new server which should have a copy of it there as well.  Once you have added your custom DLLs to the GAC, your site should work properly.

In the future, however, it is best to bundle all SharePoint-related changes as WSP packages and then let SharePoint manage the deployment of those via STSADM.

Answer (score 0):

A question for you.

what is your logical farm?is it stand alone or Multi tier?

is there any wsp?

can you pls breif the steps you have done to move your site collection.